# In Google Calendar get only the Microsoft Team Addon event's list using API

Tags: google-calendar-api, microsoft-teams

I have added the Microsoft team as an add-on in Google Calendar. Now I want to get only those events that are added as Microsoft Team events in the event list using API. How can I achieve this?

To get an event list of only Microsoft team events.

Comment: You can use [List Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to retrieve a list of events in a calendar. Please note that this is for calendar of a Microsoft 365 group.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT List Event will return only that list which directly added to ms team not as addon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/teamscal-to-gcal/ohcckoddohhnhajkjpcohionepldomji